# What do lit(0) and lit(1) do in Scala/Spark aggregate functions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this piece of code:

```
val df = resultsDf
  .withColumn("data_exploded", explode(col("data_item")))
  .groupBy("data_id","data_count")
  .agg(
    count(lit(1)).as("aggDataCount"),
    sum(when(col("data_exploded.amount")==="A",col("data_exploded.positive_amount")).otherwise(lit(0))).as("aggAmount")
  )
```

Is `lit(0)` referring to an index at position 0, or to the literal value of number `0`? The definition I see at [https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/spark-sql-functions/#:~:text=The%20lit()%20function%20creates,spanish_hi%20column%20to%20the%20DataFrame.&text=The%20lit()%20function%20is%20especially%20useful%20when%20making%20boolean%20comparisons](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/spark-sql-functions/#:%7E:text=The%20lit()%20function%20creates,spanish_hi%20column%20to%20the%20DataFrame.&text=The%20lit()%20function%20is%20especially%20useful%20when%20making%20boolean%20comparisons) says that "The `lit()` function creates a Column object out of a literal value." That definition makes me think that it is not referring to an index position but to a literal value such as a number or String. However, the usage in `count(lit(1)).as("aggDataCount")` looks like referring to an index position of a column to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lit(1)` means the literal value `1`

`count(lit(1)).as("aggDataCount")` is a way to count the number of rows (each row having a column with a value of `1` and summing this column)

Answer (score 2):

In spark lit represents literal value.

lit(0)--> put 0 as a value in column , lit(1) --> means put 1 as a value in column.

In the code you shown above they are applying an aggregation over 2 columns and keeping a count of how many rows from count(lit(1)), over a condition.

The next lit(0) is in otherwise clause which is like an else condition. lit(0) will add 0 as a literal value in the column.